# SqlClient ignores User Id in connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, connection-string, sqlclient

I have a C# application in which I use EntityFramework.
In my App.config file I got a Connection String, which contains server, database, User ID password and so forth.
But when I run my application it ignores the User ID and uses Integrated Security, which I have set to False in the connectionstring.

So why is it that my application keeps using Integrated security? I can change User ID to anything and the application stil uses integrated security.

Connection string:

```
<add name="dbConString" connectionString="Server=dbServerName;Database=databaseName;User ID=sqlUserName; Password=sqlUserPassword; Integrated Security=false; TrustServerCertificate=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Code from my db context class:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConString"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: EF Core has nothing to do with the connection string. It's not a database driver, that's ADO.NET's job. This is a bad connection string with contradictory settings - `Integrated Security=false;` but then `Integrated Security=SSPI`

Comment: Do you want to connect Windows Authentication or SQL Server authentication? If you want SQL, have you defined the login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fist of all, EF is an ORM, not a database driver. It doesn't connect to the database itself, it uses ADO.NET and the appropriate database driver.

Second, the connection string *enforces* Windows Authentication. `Integrated Security` is specified twice and the second setting overrides the first:

```
...Integrated Security=false; ...Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

To use SQL Server logins don't specify `Integrated Security` at all:

```
Server=dbServerName;Database=databaseName;User ID=sqlUserName; Password=sqlUserPassword; TrustServerCertificate=True;
```

Comment: Thank you! This explains a lot! I have fixed it now..